# Is it possible to change the caret "bubble"/"drop" color with CSS? (specific mobile)

Tags: html, css, android-cursor, caret, text-cursor

Is it possible to change the color of the bubble or drop that is under the text cursor of mobile device inputs? I changed the caret-color but it doesn't seem to have any effect, the bubble is still blue.

I don't know the correct technical term for that bubble/drop.

My code:

```css
* {
   caret-color: green;
}
```

Result/Example:

[image]

Edit: This drop/bubble only appears on Android devices apparently.

Comment: What devices/system are you using? (I don't see the 'drop' on an IOS device).

Comment: I am using an Android device. To be more specific a Xiaomi MI A3 (Anroid 110.